# How can I add 3 variables if one or two may not have a value?

Tags: javascript

I have 3 variables that are fed from a form input (`type="text"`). Each input may or may not be entered by a user. I just want to add the variables together if they have any values entered. The problem is if any of them are left blank on the form I get NaN returned.

I really enjoy figuring these things out but I haven't been able to Google my issue, I'm happy to just be told what to Google to figure this out.

```
function extrasCalc() {
    var grub = 0;
    var lime = 0;
    var aerseed = 0;

    grub = parseInt(document.getElementById("grubprice").value);
    lime = parseInt(document.getElementById("limeprice").value);
    aerseed = parseInt(document.getElementById("aerseedprice").value);
    var extrasSubtotal = grub + lime + aerseed;

    document.getElementById("sub").value = extrasSubtotal;

    console.log(grub);
    console.log(lime);
    console.log(aerseed);
    console.log(extrasSubtotal);
}
```

If only 1 or 2 of the variables have a value, I would like them to be totaled. So far all 3 have to have a value for the function to work.

Comment: Check for `NaN` before adding them up. `Number.isNaN` if you target modern browser. Or old good `value === value` check.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I'd rather go with `+value || 0` to convert a value into a number **and** deal with NaN *(convert it into a `0`)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could ensure that the values are valid this way:

```
function extrasCalc() {    
    var grub = +document.getElementById("grubprice").value || 0;
    var lime = +document.getElementById("limeprice").value || 0;
    var aerseed = +document.getElementById("aerseedprice").value || 0;

    var extrasSubtotal = grub + lime + aerseed;

    document.getElementById("sub").value = extrasSubtotal;

    console.log(grub);
    console.log(lime);
    console.log(aerseed);
    console.log(extrasSubtotal);
}
```

Basically `grub`, `lime` and `aerseed` are assigned `0`s, if their corresponding expressions evaluate to *"falsy"* values.

As a bonus, you could replace `parseInt` with `+` prefix, which does the same job and is a bit terser.

Comment: The `+` prefix looks clever, but to me it does not make the intent clear. Using `parseInt()` may be a bit more verbose, but it becomes very clear what the author is trying to do.

Comment: @hayavuk Sure, that's just a matter of preference. Just thought it would be useful to include another way of doing the same thing for the sake of it :)

Comment: If by "preference", you mean "I prefer to make my intent less clear to the reader", I guess you would be correct in that case. I normally choose to make the code as clear as possible because I don't want to confuse someone (or myself) at a later date.

Comment: @hayavuk again, I could argue that in some cases verbosity hurts readability because of the need of having to parse too much boilerplate code, but I don't want to start another holy war. Besides, this technique is commonplace enough to assume that a reader will be able to understand it right away / without too much trouble

Comment: You know what. You're right. I'm just being a stubborn ass. If it works for you, more power to you, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

to avoid empty string ""   Try this :

```
grub = +document.getElementById("grubprice").value || 0;
lime = +document.getElementById("limeprice" .value || 0;
aerseed = +document.getElementById("aerseedprice" ).value || 0;
```

Comment: with the `+` the `parseInt` has become obsolete.

Comment: @Thomas I think using + as an unary operator is not very intutive. The intent is not clear.

Comment: @GhoulAhmed The radix should be included in the `parseInt()`, like `parseInt(x, 10)`.

Comment: @hayavuk I was just saying that `parseInt(+someValue)` is a pointless. Besides that, I think it is (mostly) a matter of preference which one you use.

Comment: @Thomas You are right, I probably missed an earlier edit.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use eblow option of checking whether value is valid or not and parseInt value if available

```js
    function extrasCalc() {
        var grub = 0;
        var lime = 0;
        var aerseed = 0;

        grub = document.getElementById("grubprice").value;
        lime = document.getElementById("limeprice").value;
        aerseed = document.getElementById("aerseedprice").value;
        grub = grub? parseInt(grub) : 0;
        lime = lime? parseInt(lime): 0;
        aerseed = aerseed? parseInt(aerseed): 0;
        
        var extrasSubtotal = grub + lime + aerseed;

        document.getElementById("sub").value = extrasSubtotal;

        console.log(grub);
        console.log(lime);
        console.log(aerseed);
        console.log(extrasSubtotal);
    }
```

```html
    <input type = "text" id = 'grubprice'>
    <input type = "text" id = 'limeprice'>
    <input type = "text" id = 'aerseedprice'>
    <button onclick="extrasCalc()">Add</button><br>
    Total
    <input type = "text" id = 'sub'>
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/gNVvYX

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to add a function that will default your input to zero if no value is given.

```
function extrasCalc() {
    var grub = defaultInputToZero( parseInt(document.getElementById("grubprice").value) );
    var lime = defaultInputToZero( parseInt(document.getElementById("limeprice").value) );
    var aerseed = defaultInputToZero( parseInt(document.getElementById("aerseedprice").value) );
    var extrasSubtotal = grub + lime + aerseed;

    document.getElementById("sub").value = extrasSubtotal;

    console.log(grub);
    console.log(lime);
    console.log(aerseed);
    console.log(extrasSubtotal);
}

function defaultInputToZero(inputValue){
    if( isNaN(inputValue) ){
        return 0;
    }
    return inputValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this as well :)

```
function extrasCalc() {
    var grub = 0;
    var lime = 0;
    var aerseed = 0;

    grub = parseInt(document.getElementById("grubprice").value) ? parseInt(document.getElementById("grubprice").value) : 0;
    lime = parseInt(document.getElementById("limeprice").value) ?  parseInt(document.getElementById("limeprice").value) : 0;
    aerseed = parseInt(document.getElementById("aerseedprice").value) ?  parseInt(document.getElementById("aerseedprice").value) : 0;
    var extrasSubtotal = grub + lime + aerseed;

    document.getElementById("sub").value = extrasSubtotal;

    console.log(grub);
    console.log(lime);
    console.log(aerseed);
    console.log(extrasSubtotal);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
function extrasCalc() {
    let grub = +grubprice.value;
    let lime = +limeprice.value;
    let aerseed = +aerseedprice.value;
    
    sub.value = grub + lime + aerseed;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="grubprice" >
<input type="text" id="limeprice" >
<input type="text" id="aerseedprice" >
<br><br><button onclick="extrasCalc()">Calc</button><br><br>
<input id="sub" >
```